# Customize Sql Exception message in catch

Tags: c#, winforms, entity-framework-4, try-catch, sqlexception

I ´m doing a form where the user can Insert/Delete/Add entities. I´m using Winforms c# and entity framework 4.

Ok, the user can delete objects. Now, those objects can be referenced by other entities, so if the user wants to delete it, he will get an exception.

I catch that exception so as to show him a message that says that that object is begin used in other objects.

The exception I got is (UpdateException). But this exception can be raised if there is an update issue too. Is there any way to get the error code from Sql using this exception? Because I do have the error code that throws when this happens.

If I use SqlException I can check its number, but that's not the exception I´m receiving.

Comment: The underlying exception may have been preserved in the InnerException property of the update exception.

Comment: Instead of catching the exception why don't you detect the condition before even trying to save changes? You seem to expect this exception so you are not using exceptions as exceptions but to control the flow of your app.

Comment: Because I will have to check every relation. I will use this for every entity. And why would I do that if sql manages that itself? What you are telling me is the same that saying "why use a try catch?" Just check every error possibilty before. Just not an option. Thank for your answer though

Answer (score -2):

Do you mean *you* want to see the full exception or you want the *user* to the see the exception?

If you want to the see exception, you could write it to a text file:

```
try
{
    // do something
}
catch(SQLException sqlex)
{
    using (var file = new StreamWriter(@"C:\Users\Home\Desktop\sqlException.txt"))
    {
        file.WriteLine(sqlex.ToString());
    }
}
catch(Exception e)
{
    using (var file = new StreamWriter(@"C:\Users\Home\Desktop\generalException.txt"))
    {
        file.WriteLine(e.ToString());
    }
}
```

This will write the exception to a text file on your desktop (change directories as appropriate).

Comment: -1: Your two `StreamWriter` instances need to be in `using` blocks.

Comment: Do you mean wrap the two catch blocks in a using block? I just took this from a sample I had used with only one catch block (which works) - I only put in two catch blocks here to show that he can write different exceptions to a file. Does my answer not provide a solution to the problem?

Comment: No. Inside the `catch` blocks: `using (var file = new StreamWriter(...)){file.WriteLine(e.ToString());}`

Comment: It's all but criminal to leak resources inside of a `catch` block.

Comment: Learn something new everyday.

Comment: Based on the exception. The delete exception, I have to show a message to the user a message that he can understand of why he cant delete that object. Displayin the exception message is not understandable by a any common user..

Comment: Your question wasn't as clear as your comment above, hence my answer.

Comment: The question was clear. " Ok, the user can delete objects. Now, those objects can be referenced by other entities, so if the user wants to delete it, he will get an exception.

I catch that exception so as to show him a message that says that that object is begin used in other objects."